# Disabling Location permission on Android 6 seems to affect WiFi parameter queries

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have an Android application that accesses the device's location and then queries the WiFi parameters. Everything typically runs smoothly.

If I turn off the Location permission for the app (as I can do in Android 6) I no longer get the device's location (as is expected). However, I also get a modified **WiFiInfo** object when I try to query the WiFi parameters. In particular:

- getScanResults() normally lists all of the networks available, but with Location turned off it only contains the network the device is connected to.
- If I look at the capabilities of the network that is found, the string is empty. Normally it contains information such as the wireless encryption information.

Has anyone else seen this? I've verified it using the same code with the Location permission turned on/off on 2 different devices. Any idea on what's happening?

**Update:** On further review, I was wrong when I said that getScanResults() returns information about the AP that the device us connected to. It in fact returns an empty list. This would support the idea that Google doesn't want us to have any information about the local APs if Location permission is denied.

Comment: Are you targeting API 23?

Comment: From the mainfest:

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Why should this matter?

Comment: Okay, I just read something and understand the question. If you target API 23 then you get none of your requested permissions at install time and must ask for them dynamically at runtime. That's not the situation I'm in - I target an older API and the problem is that a user explicitly turned something off that I just believed was on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiFi-based location is basically a lookup of WiFi access point information in a giant database of known APs and locations to discover where a device is. This is what services such as Google, SkyHook, and Apple use when you enable WiFi or network location.

I suspect Google is trying to prevent an application from accessing information from which location can be derived when location is disabled. They have previously blocked access to Google Play location services when location is disabled, but this does not prevent a device from doing a scan, collecting the same data that would be sent to Google, and sending this data to a different service to discover location.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. I AM able to get the info for the AP I'm connected to but not others. I could just look up the info for that AP. Moreover, they're stopping me from getting whether the AP is using WEP/WPA/WPA2 which is something I need. Can we verify if this is really what Google is doing?